VPN scroll bar not displayed in System Status
First of all, I would like to thank you for your excellent work. I recently updated my operating system from 22.04 LTS to 24.04.1 LTS. I noticed that when we have more than eight OpenVPN profiles, the scroll bar in the System Status Area no longer appears. In this case, to connect to certain profiles, you need to access the VPN Configurations option. Is there any way to enable it?
